# Fetch DB records using Timestamp input

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have a reader table that has reader Id,reader in (TimeStamp), reader out(TimeStamp) columns.I need to fetch records from DB based on the reader in Input value.

The records which I am going to fetch should be on the same date given in the input also the time should be equal or lesser than given Time.

```
Example Values reader in - 26-APR-16 01.37.00.000000000 PM, 25-APR-16 12.11.00.000000000 AM.
```

If Date input given as 26-APR-16 02.00PM, I need to fetch records for the 26-APR-16 date with the time equal or lesser than 02.00PM

Kindly help me how to achieve this through SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ...    -- enter here which columns you want to select
from   ...    -- enter here from which table
where  ...    -- this is the clause you need help with.
```

The `where` clause is the interesting one. How you write it depends on how the "input" is given. For example, if it is given as a bind variable, let's call it `:input_timestamp`, then the `where` clause may be:

```
where reader_in between trunc(:input_timestamp) and :input_timestamp
```

`trunc` truncates a timestamp to the same date, with time 00:00:00 at midnight at the beginning of the day.